# Which is the best way to have a jupyter server running for long time?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

First question to gain some privileges...

I hope someone can answer it, maybe some links where I could find the info would be great, or the reason why is not a good idea hehe!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried running it as a service and worked like a charm for around 2 weeks, but then I encountered an issue whose responsible I haven't found.

Nevertheless, this one is a nice guide:
https://naysan.ca/2019/09/07/jupyter-notebook-as-a-service-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-python-3/